# Is there any method such as graph API or fql for tracking pending  friend requests in facebook profile?

Tags: facebook

Is there any method such as graph API or fql for tracking pending friend requests in facebook profile

Comment: You are going to need to be a little more specific.  Are you wanting to track invites that went out? Read pending invites?  Also good to note that an application can only deal with requests for THAT application.  You cant have one application tampering with another applications invites.

Comment: i want to track the count of pending friend requests appeared in my facebook profile using an facebook application either via using fql or graph api or sdk

Answer (score 3):

The fql query

```
SELECT uid_from, time, message FROM friend_request WHERE uid_to = me()
```

will return a current list of all pending friend requests

Answer (score 0):

Dear here is the solution 
By using a simple application, you can manage your pending friend requests on Facebook. Actually the application gathers all the data related to Friend Requests, Suggested Friends and Finding Friends using API. Follow the steps below to track your Pending Friend Requests.
Here is the Complete Solution for you
http://www.dradiobeats.com/how-to-track-your-pending-friend-requests-on-facebook/