# Facebook api pending friend request sent by user

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I dont find any graph api or fql query to retrieve the list of pending friend request sent by the user. Is there any way to retrieve it ?

Comment: Both http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847421/is-there-any-method-such-as-graph-api-or-fql-for-tracking-pending-friend-reques and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144284/retrieve-list-of-sent-friend-requests-from-friend-request-fql-table should give you the answer already.

Comment: Exactly! Both of them says that it's currently not possible.

Answer (score 0):

There's an FQL table called [friend_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend_request/) which shows the pending friend requests sent by or to the current session user.

However, it does not allow you to retrieve the list of pending friend request **sent by the user** because the only indexable field in this table is `uid_to`. This means that you can read the list of pending friend request **sent to the current user**, but it doesn't work the other way.

You can use the following query to retrieve the list of pending friend request sent to the current user:

```
SELECT uid_from FROM friend_request WHERE uid_to = me()
```